# How can I fix the CSRF related issues when it is enabled using Spring Boot with Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf, httpsession

I have a spring boot application. I am using Spring Security. I am facing two issues when CSRF is enabled. Please find the below issues, code and screenshots. How can I fix this?

1. Whenever the server is restarted, the login always fails the first time. It gives 404 error. But it is successful the second time.
2. I am using customAuthenticationFailureHandler in case if login is
   failed, I am setting the error message in session and redirecting it
   to login jsp to display it. It was working fine before CSRF was
   enabled. Now, it looks like the value stored in session is destroyed

**Security configuration**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    //http.csrf().disable();
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/ui/static/assets/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/register", "/forgotPassword").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/LoginPage")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
        .permitAll()
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/addDocument")
        .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler)
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied")
        .and().logout().permitAll().invalidateHttpSession(true);
}
```

**CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler**

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException exception)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        String errMsg=exception.getMessage();;
        request.getSession().setAttribute("loginErrorMessage", errMsg);
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/login?error");
  }
}
```

**Login.jsp**

```
<c:set var="params" value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string']}"/>

    <div class="account-content">
         <c:if test="${params eq 'error' && loginErrorMessage ne null}">
               <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                     <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                 </button>
                 <strong>${loginErrorMessage}</strong>
             </div>
        </c:if>

        <form action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/authenticate" class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="formLogin" data-parsley-validate="">
            <sec:csrfInput />
            <div class="form-group m-b-25">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <label for="emailaddress">Email address<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="email" name="username" id="username"  placeholder="Enter your email" data-parsley-required="true">

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group m-b-25">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/forgotPassword" class="text-danger float-right">Forgot your password?</a>
                    <label for="password">Password<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="password" id="pwd" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" data-parsley-required="true">

                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group account-btn text-center m-t-10">
                <div class="col-12">

                    <button class="btn w-lg btn-rounded btn-lg btn-primary waves-effect waves-light"
                    id="signInBtn" type="submit" value="Next" >Sign In
                    <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin" id="loadingBtn" style="display:none;"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: what's the exact URL that gives the 404?

Comment: and you disable CSRF but still have <sec:csrfInput />  in your login page

Comment: @SimonMartinell This scenario is when CSRF is enabled. I have enabled csrf and testing the whole application. The url it is trying to give 404 first time is here. Request URL: http://localhost:8081/CDSTApplication/authenticate
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 
Remote Address: [::1]:8081
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade